# Getting php session using c#

Tags: c#, php

I know how to get the source code but the website that I have been working on uses PHP session, this mean that you will need to login(which I have) and use the session ID that the server send back. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you meant `Session`, you'll need `CookieContainer`:

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(someSite);
getRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
getRequest.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse form = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader response = 
   new StreamReader(form.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
{
    formPage = response.ReadToEnd();
}
```

You first make a `GET` request to server and it'll return your SessionID in a cookie. If you need to make new requests to same server, you must pass it through and server will identify you as a returning user.

Comment: And how do I pass it to the next request? Sorry I'm a bit confuse here.