# Using Cookies on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I am searching for a cookie option for Webclient class on windows phone , please tell me if its possible or not

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Net.WebClient(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Net.WebClient%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

and why this is not working? 'Add not found ' i need a working sample

```
 wb.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "somecookie");

        wb.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] =  "somecookie";
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/0hb8kfxw(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/0hb8kfxw%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: wb.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "somecookie");
 'add' not found, i have tried

Comment: Shouldn't you use the CookieContainer of the HttpWebRequest? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: yes, right but how???             wb.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = "somecookie";
 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.cookiecontainer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class. There is a detailed page on msdn here:

[How to get and set cookies for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dd920298%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: how can i set php returning values as cookie? for example user-id

Comment: You can find more infos about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887096/getting-php-session-using-c-sharp